# Why is Area 51 not logging in?

Tags: support, area-51, login

I am not able to log in to Area 51, it says

> “Completing log in to Area 51. You will be redirected automatically.”

When that error occurs this is my url:

`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dsignup&cds=1`

It seems there are many posts about difficulty with this.

I've tried with Safari and Chrome.

Is this a known issue and are there plans to make Area 51 like other Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: You don't seem to have a user profile there linked to this account so you're signing up for the Area51 site, right?

Comment: And what is the exact error you get?

Comment: I tried to sign in and to sign up, in Safari and Chrome. The response says: “Completing log in to Area 51. You will be redirected automatically.”

Comment: That is a new one. Can you include the url that you're on when that error is shown?

Comment: This is it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.stackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252farea51.stackexchange.com%26type%3dsignup&cds=1

Comment: Clicking on that worked for me... also, now I need to go delete my unwanted A51 account.

Comment: It worked on my desktop computer but it wasn't working with my iPhone SE 2. It would be interesting to know if there are plans to make Area 51 the same codebase as other SE sites, anyway. Thanks very much

Comment: It also gets stuck here. It’s not Area 51, it’s any redirect page when on my iPhone SE 2 with iOS 15. https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackexchange.com%2fusers%2flogin-or-signup%2fdelegated%3freturnurl%3dhttps%253a%252f%252fstackexchange.com%252fusers%252f23034880%253ftab%253dinbox%2526_%253d460317698&cdl=1